# Is it possible to speed up the execution of a method in Android (Java)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, methods, adt

Good Night,

I currently have an option in my application where, upon clicking a button, a calculator should open.

The code for the method of opening the calculator I currently have is as follows:

```
 public void selectcalculator() {
     ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> items =new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
 final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
 List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);  
 for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {
 if( pi.packageName.toString().toLowerCase().contains("calcul")){
     HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
     map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
     items.add(map);

 //If calculator found, launch it

      if(items.size()>=1){
      String packageName = (String) items.get(0).get("packageName");
      Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        startActivity(i);
      } 
      else{

        //Calculator Not Found
            }
 }
       }
 }
```

The problem is that I need the calculator to be launch instantly, while with the following code it takes 1-2 seconds to load. My question is, is there any way to speed a method in Java, or, speed this method in particular?

Thank you very much,
James.

Comment: Use Traceview and figure out precisely where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the physical characteristics of the device on which you run your program, this to be more user friendly use ProgressBar while the content id loading...

read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

i hope this is helpful...

Comment: Agreed. 1 to 2 seconds is actually pretty fast all things considered. Adding a nice progress bar handler class will pay dividend over and over. Don't forget to only create on progress dialog as they don't play nicely if you have more than one active showing at a time.